# Export/Import Nightmare.js functions

Tags: node.js, nightmare

So, I have a working nightmare.js app, which works 100%. I'm now in the refactoring stage and want to put the custom functions I've made (which use nightmare.js functions) into another file, then export/import them into my main file.

The functions get called, but the nightmare functions don't actually execute or throw an error.

Why don't the nightmare functions work when importing them?

My main app:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: true,
    typeInterval: 1000,
    waitTimeout: 60 * 1000
})

const bot = require('./utils')

nightmare
    .goto(url)
    .then(_ => bot.selectByVal('#myDiv', 'myVal'))
    .then( 'yada yada yada ...')...

module.exports = nightmare;
```

Utils:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare();

module.exports = {
    selectByVal: function(el, val) {
        console.log('select' + el + val)
        try {
            return nightmare.select(el, val)
        } catch (e) {
            return e
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it's something to do with my nightmare instance not being exported/imported, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: It is nightmare a npm package?

Comment: Yes, nightmare.js is an npm package for automation of webpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot` or `utils` does not have access to `nightmare` created on the main app. You need to pass the reference.

Return a function instead which returns an object.

```
module.exports = function(nightmare) { // <-- now the same nightmare is in both file 
  return {
    selectByVal: function(el, val) {
      console.log('select' + el + val)
      try {
        return nightmare.select(el, val)
      } catch (e) {
        return e
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then on your main app,

```
const bot = require('./utils')(nightmare) // <-- pass the reference

nightmare
  .goto(url)
  .then(_ => bot.selectByVal('#myDiv', 'myVal'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Abu - you are correct. I did some more research on what was going on and this post was a big help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707536/two-sets-of-parentheses-in-a-javascript-function-call/34707642#34707642